# Sparql Query round a floating number to third digit after decimal point

Tags: sparql, rounding, rdf

I have a query which I receive a string value (?result) which is between 0-1 range (e.g. 0.99994787) and I multiply it by 100 to have a percentage view. Finally, I would like to round it to the third digit after the decimal point (e.g. 99.995) but I don't know if it is possible. This is the query I pose:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ( xsd:float(?result)*100 AS ?ASSESSMENT_VALUE) WHERE 
{
    GRAPH ?g {?obs <http://purl.org/eis/vocab/daq#value> ?result.} 

 }
```

When I use ROUND() function it is possible to round it but it is rounded to 100.0 which I don't need.

```
( ROUND( xsd:float(?ASSESSMENT_VALUE)*100) AS ?result)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://w.wiki/$fi, `(ROUND(?number*100000)/1000 AS ?round)`

Comment: That's smart thanks! Does Sparql have a way to do it like an SQL function similar to this ROUND(99.994787, 3)?

Comment: No; see https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-round.